# Allowing AJAX requests to service behind nginx proxy based on request_method

Tags: ajax, nginx, angularjs, cors

I'm new to Nginx, so pardon me if I'm being obtuse.  I have a service that is sitting behind an nginx proxy, and I am using auth_basic to prevent anyone from currently being able to hit it.  I want to allow an Angular app to hit this service, but I want to control who is allowed to perform particular request methods (GET, POST, DEL, OPTIONS), and using auth_basic doesn't seem like the best bet, since I don't want to hardcode the login/password into the JS (duh).  The only way I can figure out how to do this is to say:

```
if ($request_method = OPTIONS)
{ 
        proxy_pass_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        proxy_pass_header Access-Control-Allow_Methods GET, OPTIONS;
        etc...
}
```

At this point, I'd allow GET and OPTIONS requests from anyone, but I want to restrict POST, DEL to only from certain locations (such as internally, or from a trusted IP).  Currently, though, if I put proxy_pass_header into that block, it says that the directive is not allowed.  I've seen other examples where people use add_header inside an if block like that, so I'm confused why that isn't working.

So first of all, is this the best way of doing things, and if not, does someone have another recommendation?  If it is the best way of handling things, what am I doing wrong here?

Any help would be appreciated.  I find the nginx documentation to be very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `deny/allow` directives from `ngx_http_access_module`.

```
location / {
    deny  192.168.1.1;
    allow 192.168.1.0/24;
    allow 10.1.1.0/16;
    allow 2001:0db8::/32;
    deny  all;
}
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html